# CNN training data size for determing the winner of tic-tac-toe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn machine learning with tensorflow and wrote a program that uses CNNs to determine game results for a given tic-tac-toe board. Its inputs and outputs are -

Input  - An array of 9 elements that represents the board (0=empty, 1='X', 2='O')

Output - An array of 3 elements ([1,0,0]=draw, [0,1,0]=player1 won, [0,0,1]=player2 won).

Below is the tensorflow graph part of the program (it is a modified version of tensorflow tutorial at - https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros).

```
baseFeatureSize = 64
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 9])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 3, 3, 1])
W_conv1 = nn_utils.weight_variable([2, 2, 1, baseFeatureSize])
b_conv1 = nn_utils.bias_variable([baseFeatureSize])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(nn_utils.conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
W_conv2 = nn_utils.weight_variable([2, 2, baseFeatureSize, baseFeatureSize * 2])
b_conv2 = nn_utils.bias_variable([baseFeatureSize * 2])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(nn_utils.conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
W_fc1 = nn_utils.weight_variable([3 * 3 * baseFeatureSize * 2, baseFeatureSize * 4])
b_fc1 = nn_utils.bias_variable([baseFeatureSize * 4])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv2, [-1, 3 * 3 * baseFeatureSize * 2])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
W_fc2 = nn_utils.weight_variable([baseFeatureSize * 4, 3])
b_fc2 = nn_utils.bias_variable([3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

def conv2d(x, W): return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
def max_pool_2x2(x): return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
```

**Questions** - The above model works well but requires to train with over 700k inputs to get output prediction accuracy up to 80%. But the total possible permutations of the game board are less than [300K](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269066/game-combinations-of-tic-tac-toe). If I feed just all of the unique permutations, then the accuracy worsens.

1. Is it normal for CNNs to require training data size to be much larger than all possible permutations of the inputs? I'm assuming this is not true or else they'd not be able to play chess and go etc, so what am I doing wrong?
2. Based on your experience, how big a training sample size would typically make sense for this setup?

Comment: There are 19,683 game states, even counting impossible ones and ignoring symmetry. That's as opposed to move sequences which you asked in the linked question - but you are not using move sequences, the CNN is clearly processing the state of the board in your code. Really a CNN is a bad choice here, and your network is far too complex for the task you are attempting. You could likely get 100% accuracy using simple 1-hidden-layer fully connected network.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, thanks for the correction regarding the game states, I had misinterpreted that question. I'll try a simpler model as you suggested.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a cnn is a bad choice though? I'm a newbie. Assuming a cnn could do the job (while probably being too much for this problem), is the lower accuracy because of it being overly complicated?

Comment: I cannot really say where the CNN is going wrong in your case, so it is just a gut reaction. If I knew for certain then I would post an answer, but to do that I'd basically had to of already done your project or something very similar. I suggest that if simplifying your network is the fix, that you post your own answer here later . . .

Comment: As stated, CNN is the last thing you should consider for this task. You're asking for troubles with such a complicated network.

Comment: @StudentT  Thank you, understood. I'm just a beginner and experimenting. My eventual goal is to create the full tic tac toe game that learns from opponents, this is just the first step in which I'm trying things out. This is the network that I was going to use for the full game, would a cnn be a good choice there? Also, should I expect that a more suitable model would require training data smaller than the total permutations?

Comment: @Achilles No. CNN is not a good choice. Try a simple single layer, if not two layers. Don't do CNN here. A better model would require far less data.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with some other approaches as well and discovered that MLPs produce equivalent or better results for this problem. Thanks to the commenters Neil Slater and Student T for pointing me in the right direction.

For anyone interested, this is the model that eventually worked for me

```
boardSize = 3*3
featureSize = #I experimented with 500-1500 with varying results here
output = 3
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, boardSize])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, featureSize])
learning_rate = 0.01
seed = 128
weights = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([boardSize, featureSize], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([featureSize, output], seed=seed))
}
biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([featureSize], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output], seed=seed))
}
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
hidden_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden']), biases['hidden'])
hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer)
hidden_layer2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer, tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([featureSize, featureSize], seed=seed))), 
                tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_num_units], seed=seed)))
hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer2)

y_conv = tf.matmul(hidden_layer2, weights['output']) + biases['output']
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_conv, labels=y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```